selenium google extension automation Traceback error
To keep my trust wallet account safe, I constantly log out of my account and I decided to write a python code to quickly log it back in, but when I try to select it with things like xpath or css selection, I get the error in the photo. Also, my code is below.
Code
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# chrome ayarlamaları
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('C:/Users/JAXXXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/egjidjbpglichdcondbcbdnbeeppgdph/2.11.0_0.crx')

# sürücü başlatma
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

time.sleep(10)
# Butonun yüklenmesini bekleme
buton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ph-no-capture w-full block flex-1 outline-none bg-transparent title-text font-medium text-left")
buton1.click()

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JAXXXXX\Desktop\aa\trust.py", line 17, in <module>
    buton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ph-no-capture w-full block flex-1 outline-none bg-transparent title-text font-medium text-left")
  File "C:\Users\JAXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\JAXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\JAXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ph-no-capture w-full block flex-1 outline-none bg-transparent title-text font-medium text-left"}
  (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.92)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66C381502+60802]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C2FAC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C1B7CE4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C206D4D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C206E1C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C24CE37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C22ABBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C24A224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C22A923]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C1F8FEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C1F9C21]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66C68411D+3217821]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66C6C60B7+3488055]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66C6BF03F+3459263]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66C43B846+823494]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C305F9F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C300EC4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C301052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66C2F18A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9911E7344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9929626B1+33]

I tried XPath and CSS Selector.

We can't really help much except guess without the relevant HTML in the question as text, properly formatted

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Without seeing the HTML, your CSS selector is almost assuredly the problem.
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ph-no-capture w-full block flex-1 outline-none bg-transparent title-text font-medium text-left")

None of those are tags... they all appear to be classes which means the selector should be
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ph-no-capture.w-full.block.flex-1.outline-none.bg-transparent.title-text.font-medium text-left").click()

All of those classes are probably not required to uniquely find the element but I can't determine that without seeing the relevant HTML or the page itself.

I tried this but it still gives error

Well, there's nothing we can do until you update your question with more info.

what type of info?

Read my comment under your question


Read my comment under your question again.
